# Get names of firebase database nodes without getting their values and store them as list in Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Please, i ran into a problem... I want to get the names of all nodes and store it as a list. Take for instance see below codes

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
databaseReference.child("users").child("students");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                CourseRegistrationModel courseRegistrationModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(CourseRegistrationModel.class);
                courseRegistrationModelArrayList.add(courseRegistrationModel);
            }

            requireActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                CourseRegistrationAdapter courseRegistrationAdapter = new CourseRegistrationAdapter(requireActivity, onCourseAddedListener, courseRegistrationModelArrayList);
                fragmentCourseRegistrationBinding.registerCoursesList.setAdapter(courseRegistrationAdapter);
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            requireActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(requireActivity, "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        }
    });
```

But i'm not getting anything in the list.
See my [image: Database tree]

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK always retrieves the full node at a path. There is no way to make it read only the keys.

But your code can process the result to only *use* the keys:

```
databaseReference.child("users").child("students").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("Firebase", dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: I just want to get the names which are
2021484015 and 2021484077 then store them as list

Comment: I tested your code and i got users and courses

Comment: Ah yeah, I see now what else was wrong: you were reading the wrong path. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not still working

Comment: "it's still not working" is hard to help with. What does the code log when you run it?

Comment: It's not showing anything in logcat

Comment: when i log it, i got users, students. But what i want is the names of  students children node like 2021484015, 2021484077, etc without getting the data

Comment: Are you sure you updated with the edit I did in my answer? It sounds like you might have misssed that one. --- If it still doesn't work after that, please edit your question to include the code you now have at the bottom of it.